# How to make a C++20 stackful coroutine's `co_await` accept any `T` return type?

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm trying to implement a stackful coroutine system in C++20, based on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61696746/supsending-thrugh-multiple-nested-coroutines).
The problem with the linked code is that it works only if the nested coroutines are of the same `task<T>` type, so I'm trying to extend it in order to be possible to `co_await` a task with any `T`. In other words, it's OK the return object always being a `task<T>`, but the awaiting coroutine return object's `T` can be different from the awaited coroutine return object's `T`.

This is my code so far:

```cpp
template<class T>
class task {
public:
    class promise_type {
    protected:
        T value;

        std::coroutine_handle<> innerHandler{};
        std::coroutine_handle<> outerHandler{};

        friend class task;

    public:
        task get_return_object() {
            return task(std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>::from_promise(*this));
        }

        auto initial_suspend() {
            return std::suspend_never{};
        }

        auto final_suspend() noexcept {
            return std::suspend_always{};
        }

        auto return_value(T v) {
            this->value = std::move(v);
            return std::suspend_always{};
        }

        void unhandled_exception() {
            abort("Unhandled exception in Coroutine");
        }
    };

    explicit task(std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> handle) : handle(handle) {}

    task(const task&) = delete;

    task(task&& c) noexcept : handle(std::exchange(c.handle, nullptr)) {}

    task& operator=(const task&) = delete;

    task& operator=(task&& c) noexcept {
        this->handle = std::exchange(c.handle, nullptr);
        return *this;
    }

    ~task() {
        if (this->handle) {
            this->handle.destroy();
        }
    }

    constexpr bool await_ready() const noexcept {
        return !this->handle || this->handle.done();
    }

    bool await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> h) {
        h.promise().innerHandler = this->handle;
        this->handle.promise().outerHandler = h;
        return true;
    }

    constexpr T await_resume() const noexcept {
        return std::move(this->handle.promise().value);
    }

    bool next() {
        auto cur = this->handle;
        while (cur) {
            if (!cur.promise().innerHandler) {
                while (!cur.done()) {
                    cur.resume();
                    if (!cur.done()) {
                        return true;
                    }

                    if (cur.promise().outerHandler) {
                        cur = cur.promise().outerHandler;
                        cur.promise().innerHandler = nullptr;
                    }
                    else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }

            cur = cur.promise().innerHandler;
        }

        return !cur.done();
    }

private:
    std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> handle;
};
```

The code is failing to compile on `h.promise().innerHandler = this->handle;` in `bool await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> h)`, because `std::coroutine_handle<>` doesn't expose the `promise()` member. The code from the linked post works because OP declares `h` as `std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>`, but I can't use it or else I'm stuck again at `co_await`ing return types with the same `T`.

I've also tried using `await_trasform()` but it is even more difficult to understand than what I'm already struggling with, using these C++ coroutines.

How could I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

So in the end I managed to find a way to do it.
Basically turns out that with `std::coroutine_handle::from_address()` I can cast a promise type-deleted `std::coroutine_handle<>` to one specific to my `promise_type`, like so:

```cpp
// With h being a std::coroutine_handle<>
auto cH = std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>::from_address(h.address());
```

There isn't any compile-time check in place to make sure that `h` is actually castable to `std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>`, and I think there are some edge cases that require them, but at least for my application I can safely make this assumption.

This is the complete code for class `task`:

```cpp
template<class T>
class task {
public:
    class promise_type {
    protected:
        std::unique_ptr<T> value;

        std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> innerHandler{};
        std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> outerHandler{};

        friend class task;

    public:
        task get_return_object() {
            return task(std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>::from_promise(*this));
        }

        auto initial_suspend() {
            return std::suspend_never{};
        }

        auto final_suspend() noexcept {
            return std::suspend_always{};
        }

        auto return_value(T v) {
            this->value = std::make_unique<T>(std::move(v));
            return std::suspend_always{};
        }

        void unhandled_exception() {
            abort("Unhandled exception in Coroutine");
        }
    };

    explicit task(std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> handle) : handle(handle) {}

    task(const task&) = delete;

    task(task&& c) noexcept : handle(std::exchange(c.handle, nullptr)) {}

    task& operator=(const task&) = delete;

    task& operator=(task&& c) noexcept {
        this->handle = std::exchange(c.handle, nullptr);
        return *this;
    }

    ~task() {
        if (this->handle) {
            this->handle.destroy();
        }
    }

    constexpr bool await_ready() const noexcept {
        return !this->handle || this->handle.done();
    }

    bool await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> h) {
        auto cH = std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>::from_address(h.address());
        cH.promise().innerHandler = this->handle;
        this->handle.promise().outerHandler = cH;
        return true;
    }

    constexpr T await_resume() const noexcept {
        return std::move(*this->handle.promise().value);
    }

    bool next() {
        auto cur = this->handle;
        while (cur) {
            if (!cur.promise().innerHandler) {
                while (!cur.done()) {
                    cur.resume();
                    if (!cur.done()) {
                        return true;
                    }

                    if (cur.promise().outerHandler) {
                        cur = cur.promise().outerHandler;
                        cur.promise().innerHandler = nullptr;
                    }
                    else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }

            cur = cur.promise().innerHandler;
        }

        return !cur.done();
    }

private:
    std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> handle;
};
```